# Two-dimensional discrete aleatory variable prediction

Tags: prediction, discrete-data

I hope someone can help me a bit facing this problem. I have many item samples from a database (let's say 1000 for example) with two attributes: a price from a range of possible prices (0 to 8000€ for example) and color (only two options, black or white).

I got all these samples and I assumed they represent a Two-dimensional discrete aleatory variable, where one variable (X) is the price, and the other (Y) is the color. Having this I calculated and plotted the Joint density function being the price the x-axis, probability the y-axis and the color the z-axis. The graph seems to follow (roughly) a Normal distribution. In addition I calculated and plotted as well the Conditional Density function fx(x|Y=black) and the Percentiles for black and white options. Black items seem to gather in low prices.

My question is: having all this information, how can I predict what's the probability of being 'black' (unknown) for a new incoming sample with a certain price (known). I'd like to set a probability percentage threshold to trigger a warning for 'high possibility of new incoming item being black'

Thanks a lot,

Nacho